# Sending data using ajax to php file not working

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to send data from the fields to a PHP file, but it always returns null.

Is my approach correct, or I'm missing something?

Thank in advance.
my ajax

```
$.ajax({
url: '/GetData.php',
dataType: 'json',
type: 'POST',
data: {
a:a,
b:b,
c:c
},
contentType: 'application/json',
success: function(response){
console.log('success '+ JSON.stringify(response));
search_table =  JSON.stringify(response)

$('#mytable').html(search_table);

},
error: function(err){
console.log('error '+JSON.stringify(err));
//alert(JSON.stringify(err))
}
});
```

my GetData.php file

```
<?php
 $a = $_GET["a"];
 $b = $_GET["b"];
 $c = $_GET["c"];

$remote_url = "http://mydomain/GetDataDetails/?name=".$a."&age=".$b."&degree=".$c;
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
'method'=>"GET",
)
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$out=json_decode(file_get_contents($remote_url, false, $context),true);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($out);
?>
```

Comment: You use method POST and in GetData use method GET, change like  `$a = $_POST["a"];` or change method in ajax method

Comment: When posting code, _please_ make sure it's sensibly formatted. You want to make it a s easy as possible for us to read it.

Comment: You can also remove `contentType: 'application/json'` from the ajax request since you most likely just want to post the data in the "normal" way.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini thanks for your replay. I try what you said but still not working.

Comment: So instead of fixing the formatting of the code, you just made it worse. Please _indent_ your code properly. it's hard to follow the flow without any indention.

Comment: @IDI the variable a-b-c where you create? have you tried type: 'GET', ?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini thank you, after changing the code as ```$_POST``` and remove ```contentType: 'application/json'``` it works now.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you, after changing the code as ```$_POST``` and remove ```contentType: 'application/json'``` it works now.

Comment: Acept answer for community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from comment:

- Change from `$_GET` to `$_POST` in PHP
- Remove `contentType: 'application/json',` from the Ajax request